# Enviar ficheros access.log en tiempo real

Tags: php, api, apache, curl

Para un proyecto, necesito enviar los logs generados por apache en tiempo real de un servidor y recibirlo en otro. Es un proyecto desde un servidor compartido hosting, solo se puede interactuar con esos datos con un script en php por ejemplo o desde FTP. ¿Se podría hacer una API en php para recoger los nuevos registros y enviarlos en tiempo real al otro servidor? ¿que opciones proponéis para poder hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: `rsync` parece ser una mejor opción para eso.

Comment: Por lo que he leído no me sirve, es necesario instalar el servicio en el servidor, ¿es correcto?, en la parte origen es un servidor hosting compartido, no hay acceso ssh con root para instalar servicios, en la parte destino el servidor si se podría, que sería un servidor dedicado. ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Eh, la pregunta es muy amplia como está y tiene pinta de que será cerrada. Sin embargo, lo que he visto es que a) si el hosting tiene cPanel, permite crear un cronjob que invoca algún script PHP, b) usan alguna funcionalidad de CodeIgniter o Laravel para programar el cronjob.

Comment: En el caso de ejecutar el script es lo que menos me preocupa, puedo llamarlo desde b).  Lo que necesito es saber que utilizar para hacer ese script y pueda enviar de manera segura de a) hosting a b) los logs de apache. Gracias